# Stored Procedure/Function Logic for Summing of account balances

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
Version B       C       D       output  Account number  Balance
----------------------------------------------------------------
2       1283    1303    0       4071    1                10
2       1283    1304    0       4072    2                20
3       1283    4068    1303    4071    1                30
3       1283    4069    1304    4072    4                40
4       1283    4071    4068    4071    5               -50
4       1283    4072    4069    4072    2                90
```

Version,B,C,D are columns present in all_details table.Column "Output" is the desired output i wish to achieve and i wish to store all the above columns in a table until output

How in the first line of Output i placed 4071 is

```
1) i took 1303 in column C and then looked into column D
2) then it is again referring to 4068 in column C 
3) Then i took 4068 and it is refering to 4071 in column C its like a linkage
```

I'm using column B as it is related information to other columns.

i need a another column output so that i can identify related links and sum up balances.For example

I'll sum up related links 1303,4068,4071 balances Group by **Output**  i'll get 10+40 = 50 for account 1 and -50 for account 5 corresponding to 4071

Comment: What is your query? What is the table structure? Please add some more information, it is very unclear now.

Comment: I'm not able to format please edit to see the structure

Comment: explain the meaning of your data. what we see is a bunch of useless numbers dropped here and there.

Comment: Thats a difficult one as you need looping to find the highest one. I'm not sure if that can be done with an SQL statement.

Comment: I think you have to see the numbers as version numbers. Column C and D are related as being consecutive versions, C being the current version and D being the previous version. So if you see version 1303 has predecessor 0, so no version before. But version 4068 is the successor of 1303. And 4071 is the successor of 4068. There is no later version for 4071 so for 4071 the outcome should be 4071 an also for all its predecessors.

Comment: Thanks Juru, i have to find some way to do this i'm trying to understand something about CONNECT By but not sure it will solve the purpose

Answer (score 1):

So from what I am understanding, you need to have something that recursively finds the last linked number, for a given number. These links exists between your `Column C` and `Column D`.
I am assuming that Column B is a grouping type number, but I am certain that you might be able to figure out how to adjust the function to return what you need it to return.

What you will need to do is build a [`SQL function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186755.aspx) that will iterate through your table and follow the links until it can find no more links. Details and example follow below as to how one can do that.

So firstly the building up of the sample data, as you presented them (**NOTE this creates a table on your database, be careful!**)

```
-- Building testing data
if exists (select 1
             from sys.objects
            where name = 'versionhistory'
              and type = 'U')
begin
  drop table versionhistory
end

create table versionhistory
      ( versionno  int,
        colB       int,
        colC       int,  -- Current Value
        colD       int ) -- Previous value

insert versionhistory
     ( versionno,
       colB,
       colC,
       colD )
values -- B     C     D
     ( 2, 1283, 1303, 0),
     ( 2, 1283, 1304, 0),
     ( 3, 1283, 4068, 1303),
     ( 3, 1283, 4069, 1304),
     ( 4, 1283, 4071, 4068),
     ( 4, 1283, 4072, 4069)
go
```

Now we need to create the function that will iterate through the tables records, follow the links between the two columns until it can find no more links, then return the last linked value.

```
-- Create the function that will get the last entry for a give number
if exists (select 1 from sys.objects where name = 'f_get_last_ver' and type = 'FN')
begin
  drop function f_get_last_ver
end
go
create function f_get_last_ver
     ( @colB int,
       @colC int )
  returns int
  as
  begin
    declare @nextColC int,
            @lastColC int

    -- Initial check if there is a 'next' version
    select @nextColC = isnull((select vh.colC
                                 from versionhistory vh
                                where vh.colB = @colB
                                  and vh.colD = @colC), 0)

    -- This will handle the loop until there are no more entries linked
    while isnull(@nextColC, 0) <> 0
    begin
      -- Store our last value for return purposes
      select @lastColC = @nextColC

      -- Get our next version number that is linked
      select @nextColC = isnull((select vh.colC
                                   from versionhistory vh
                                  where vh.colB = @colB
                                    and vh.colD = @nextColC), 0)
    end

    -- Return our last value, otherwise if no linkage was found, return the input
    return isnull(@lastColC, @colC)
  end
go
```

And finally here you have the usage of the function.

```
-- Example usage
select dbo.f_get_last_ver(1283, 1303), -- returns 4071
       dbo.f_get_last_ver(1283, 1304)  -- returns 4072
```

**Remember to clean up your database when done testing/experimenting with this**

I hope that the comments inside the function will explain enough of what is happening, but if something is unclear, ask away.

**P.S.** Please rename your columns and variables in your actual code into more meaningful column names and variables, since B, C, D doesn't really explain what they are used for.

Comment: But I'm thinking of ways to write in a select Query without writing a storedProcedure/Function.Any way thanks for your time and explanation

Comment: The above is just an example and actual table contains huge data.Just for masking i have used a.b.c.d conventions

Comment: With a function the sql server can optimize it efficiently. I have also used such a method for rate lookups that contained millions of records, so it's speed is efficient. There will unfortunately not be a single running query (that I am aware) that will be able to follow the links like that, without a loop of some sort.

Comment: I understand but just thought to post if it is possible through  Select query because my system restricts logic to be written in Select query otherwise i have to create a table for it to store the result of stored proc/function just to avoid it i'm trying to write in select query